# Select text before # using preg_replace in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to take 'text' from 'text#'. I try this code:

```
echo preg_replace('/(.*)\#/', '', 'text#');
```

but it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What are you getting then?

Comment: What `doesn't work`?

Comment: You only need to read a basic tutorial, what you are trying to do is very easy.

Comment: What do you mean with "take"? Remove? Can you write an example of input and desired output? e.g. "blah#aaa" -> I want to get "aaa" or whatever

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include reference to your "text" - see the `$1`:

```
echo preg_replace('/(.*)\#/', '$1', 'text#');
```

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to using regex for this task, you could (or actually should) just use `strpos` and `substr`:

```
echo substr_before('test#', '#')."\n"; // test# -> test
echo substr_before('foo#bar', '#'); // foo#bar -> foo

function substr_before($haystack, $needle) {
    // check if $haystack contains $needle, if so directly get the index of $needle
    if (($index = strpos($haystack, $needle)) !== false) {
        // chop off $needle and everything that trails it
        return substr($haystack, 0, $index);
    }
    return $haystack;
}
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1204e61693ba6b2ed765256495fddb6d4a7847e5)